# CSS Repeated Value Checker?

Tags: css

This isn't really a programming question per say, but I am trying to find a program or online tool that will combine alike values in css.

Example:

```
.someclass{
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.anotherclass{
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Would be turned into:

```
.someclass .anotherclass{
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

I guess I could write a parser myself but I don't want to do that if one already exists. I already checked previous questions here and I find the questions similar but not what I want.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but the `csscss` ruby gem will give you some details about duplicated selectors.

http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some options out there that can help you leverage the amount of CSS you use. One of them, for example, is [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/). Another option is the well known [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). A most recent CSS preprocessor is [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/).

Here is an [interesting comparison](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2013/03/08/less-vs-sass-vs-stylus.html) between the three.

I think if you properly bet on one of them you will be able to have a better outcome yourself.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Why do these all require complicated installs, or installs of 3rd party software? Is their not a 3rd party parser for windows? I think I might as well make a portable one myself. :/

Comment: these don't solve the problem of 'here is my css, find and fix my duplicate selectors'.

Comment: Estimated @Jakes625 it would be a big pleasure to have a github link to your idea. Anyhow, please note that we are in times of not reinventing the wheel. Well, just in case here is a list of not up-to-date CSS Organizer tools, if this is what you need(http://cashrevelations.com/magazine/2010/09/beautify-css/).

Comment: @RamonAraujo I couldn't seem to find any working tools. I'm going to have to create it myself. I'll just parse all selectors, then get each value for each rule. Then if multiple match, combine into like selectors. Won't be too hard to make, I'll have to ignore syntax errors for now though.

Comment: Hi @Jakes625 please post here the github project link, as it may be interesting to see the development as it goes. There are SEVERAL things to take into account when building a general tool like that. Wish you the best mate ;)